# How do I pull the first result from some json?

Tags: swift

I'm using Swift, and I haven't had this problem before. This is my code:

```
 var item = jsonResult["items"][0] as! NSDictionary
```

I get an error for the whole line saying

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'Int'

Any help?

The rest of my code is here:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 600.0)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        let urlPath = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/10861780/posts?key=AIzaSyDZ86TotGGMQpRJ6GCNrCMDMaqwbQAbfz4"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
            } else {
            let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil) as!
                NSDictionary

                var item = jsonResult["items"][0] as! NSDictionary




            }

    })

        task.resume()



        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

        // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
        // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
        newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")

        // Save the context.
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Blog Item"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

            var error: NSError? = nil
            if !context.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
    }

    // MARK: - Fetched results controller

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
             abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }    
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Update:
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
            case .Move:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    /*
     // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

     func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
         // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
     */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure what's going on because you haven't provided much to go on.

You didn't provide the code that deserialized your JSON data into objects. It's probably a collection of Foundation objects.

It sounds like `jsonResult` is an NSDictionary. If so, the value for each key is going to be of type AnyObject? (optional AnyObject.)

You will need to cast it to the array type you're expecting:

```
if let array = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray,
  let item = array[0] as? NSDictionary
{
  //Unwrapped the dictionary inside the array inside the dictionary.
}
else
{
  //There's something rotten in the state of Denmark
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var item = ( jsonResult["items"] as! [ NSDictionary ] )[ 0 ]
```

Or restrict keys to String type:

```
    var item = ( jsonResult["items"] as! [ [ String: AnyObject ] ] )[ 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will various according to the json that you get. It will be better if you post the json result here.

jsonResult will definitely be a NSDictionary. But tbe type of `jsonResult["item"]` is still unclear to me.

If the `jsonResult["item"]` is a NSDictionary, I guess there is not such a saying as "the first element". NSDictionary is a key-value pair, I'm not sure whether it has some sort of sequence for it.

If `jsonResult["item"]` is an array, you should get it and set it to a NSArray. Use `let itemArray = jsonResult["item"] as! NSArray` instead. Then you can use itemArray[0] to get the first item.

So please check what `jsonResult["item"]` exactly is.

Hope this helps.